# Advanced Global Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code which is working well for editing a link to send a user to a website based on location but Id like to expand on this code in two ways:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) {
        var country = data.address.country;
        var urls = {
            'Australia': 'www.website.com.au',
            'New Zealand': 'www.website.co.nz'
        }
        var locstring = "/contact_us.html";
        var locstring2 = "/about_us.html";
        var cchUrl = 'www.website.com';
        if(urls[country]) {
            cchUrl = urls[country];
        }
        //alert(cchUrl);
        $("#global").attr('href', 'http://' + cchUrl + locstring);
        $("#global2").attr('href', 'http://' + cchUrl + locstring2);
    });
});

<a href="http://www.website.com/contact_us.html" id="global" target="_blank">Contact Us</a>

<a href="http://www.website.com/about_us.html" id="global2" target="_blank">About Us</a>
```

1. As you can see I had to setup two variables (locstring, locstring2) and two id's (global, global2) to send the user to two different locations, is it possible I can use the id global to change the domain but it doesn't matter what path comes after the domain. I want to simplify the code so www.thiswillchange.com/thiswontchange using one ID rather than setting up multiple ID's & variables for different links.
2. As a different project can I use this code (using the changes from point 1.) to create an "on page load" so if the user for example surfs to the page www.website.co.nz/contact_us.html that it would detect they are from Australia and send them to the www.website.com.au/contact_us.html site and vice versa or would that require a whole different approach.

Keeping in mind that I may want to add more countries to the list in the future as I add more sites.

EDIT: maybe I should elaborate a bit more the links are in text on an international slash page, there is no menu, I just use the global redirect to change the links domain to send the user to the correct website for there location and then the path to the page.

Comment: what does this mean: "is it possible that I can make it so I can use the id global to change the url but it doesn't matter what path comes after the domain."

Comment: Sorry terrible typing on my behalf, in an example the text would be "click here to learn about us or click here to contact us" this is on a international splash page, the jQuery then changes the domain in the link to send them to the right domain for there countries contact us page, what I wanted to achieve is instead of making a new variable (locstring, locstring2) for every new link, I could just change the domain and anything/any path after the domain wouldn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that's feasible for you, but you could build the menu from javascript instead of writing html and then changing it.
That way you can also easily add more menu items without having to change the html and introducing more global variables.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) {

        var country = data.address.country;
        var urls = {
            'Australia': 'www.website.com.au',
            'New Zealand': 'www.website.co.nz'
        };

        var menu = {
            'Contact Us'  : '/contact_us.html',
            'About Us'    : '/about_us.html'
        };

        var cchUrl = 'www.website.com';
        if (urls[country]) {
            cchUrl = urls[country];
        }
        for(name in menu){
            $('#menu').append($('<a/>',{'text':name,'href':'http://'+cchUrl+'/'+menu[name]}));
        }

    });
});

<div id="menu"></div>
```

---

Next try:
Here all the links get the same class. Then the domain in the href of each of them will get replaced by the cchUrl.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) {
        var country = data.address.country;
        var urls = {
            'Australia': 'www.website.com.au',
            'New Zealand': 'www.website.co.nz'
        }

        var cchUrl = 'www.website.com';
        if(urls[country]) {
            cchUrl = urls[country];
        }

        $('.global').each(function(){
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            $(this).attr('href', href.replace(/http:\/\/.*?\//,'http://'+cchUrl+'/'));
        });
    });
});

<a href="http://www.website.com/contact_us.html" class="global" target="_blank">Contact Us</a>
<a href="http://www.website.com/about_us.html" class="global" target="_blank">About Us</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, maybe I should elaborate a bit more the links are in text a international slash page, there is no menu, I just use the global redirect to send the user to the correct website for there location and then the path to the page.

Comment: webmonkey237 I suggest you reconsider this; it looks like Andy's solution will do exactly what you want. Your idea of replacing the domain of an already built <a>'s href attr requires ugly regexp-based parsing, whereas Andy will just build what you want from the beginning.

Comment: @webmonkey237 Sorry, i still don't completely understand it. Do you want people to automatically get redirected to their country page? In your example you had 2 links and then changed their hrefs to the localized ones. Thats exactly what i did, only that i created the links from javascript and I just named the div where i insert the links menu. You say there is no menu, but the two links (contact, about) are on the intl. page, or are they not?

Comment: Sorry what I'm trying to do is make it more simple e.g. so all I have to do is put the ONE ID "global" on a link to change the domain, rather than having to create a new variable and new ID and setup a new path every time I have a new link, so the ID "global" will change the domain based on the country. www.thiswillchange.com/thiswontchange hopefully this is clearer

Comment: @webmonkey237 ok, i updated my answer, hopefully this is closer to what you're looking for :)

Comment: Awesome, looks perfect, ill give it a try soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
function update(id, domain) {
    var old = $(id).attr('href')
    $(id).attr('href', old.replace(/http:\/\/.+?\/(.*?)/, 'http://'+domain+'/$1'))
}
update("#global", cchUrl)
```